# Predict failure for time series data

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, cross-validation

I have a dataset (csv file) in R with the following variables:
- date (m/d/y)
- machine number (for example "XTR004")
- Failure ( binary, 0 or 1)
- attribute 1 (int)
- attribute 2 (int)
- attribute 3 (int)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syaex.png)

I have 6 months of data. Each day a log (1 row) is created that displays the date, machine number, whether the machine failed or not and the 3 attributes that should be related to the failure. When a machine fails (failure = 1), a new log (row) is not created the next day. In other words, the first date has a lot of rows, the last one has a small amount of rows

Goal: I would like to predict failure (with Rstudio) using those 3 attributes. The models that I would like to use are 1) logistic regression, 2) random forest, 3) neural networks.

Problem: Does anyone have any advice on how to split the data into a training and validation set (80/20 or cross validation) followed by using the models above for this specific case? The date and machine number together can be seen as the 'primary key'. Therefore I am not sure whether to:
- Make 2 groups of machines with all the logs that are related to those machines
- Make 2 groups that are split using a certain date (This implies that certain machines that live long are part of both groups)

I think the first strategy makes more sense, but I haven't found a way to split the data (using a 80/20 one-time split or a 5 or 10 fold cross validation). I assume I would have to group the data according to its machine number? Does anyone have any example I could take a look at or any sample code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have to provide a representative sample of your data, or fake data that you think represent your structure so we can help you. Also, there are many examples online on how to split a dataset into train/test.

Comment: @AntoniosK Thanks for the feedback. I included a screenshot of a very small sample. I found a lot of resources on splitting the data, but I didn't find anything on how to do it if a dataset includes a column 'date'. The only resource I found splits the dataset into two based on a certain date (so training set is before that date and validation set is after that date).

Comment: Personally I'd split the data using the machine number columns. In that way my training and test data will consists of all dates of specific machine names. I wouldn't like to have some rows (days) of a specific machine as training and other as test data. For example, if machine `XTR004` randomly gets in the training data, then all its rows will go to the training data as well. Does that sound reasonable? Do you know how to do it?

Comment: That makes sense! I agree. Do you have any additional resources on the coding part?

Comment: I do have some code to do that sampling and splitting to train and test groups and will probably post it as an answer with some comments. Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a train/test split process, based on the (unique) machine names you have in your original dataset.

```
# example dataset
df = data.frame(Date = c(rep("03/20/2001", 4), rep("03/21/2001", 4)),
                Machine = rep(c("XTR003","XTR004","XTR005","XTR006"), 2),
                Attr1 = c(0,0,10,5,0,4,0,8),
                Failure = c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

# check how it looks like
df

#         Date Machine Attr1 Failure
# 1 03/20/2001  XTR003     0       0
# 2 03/20/2001  XTR004     0       1
# 3 03/20/2001  XTR005    10       0
# 4 03/20/2001  XTR006     5       0
# 5 03/21/2001  XTR003     0       1
# 6 03/21/2001  XTR004     4       0
# 7 03/21/2001  XTR005     0       0
# 8 03/21/2001  XTR006     8       1

# create a vector of unique machine names
machine_vec = unique(df$Machine)

# calculate number of unique machines in your train dataset
# here we want 70% of machines to be in the train dataset
# (this is NOT the number of rows of your train dataset, but the number of unique machines)
N_train = round(length(machine_vec) * 0.7)

# randomly select which machine names will create your train dataset
train_machines = sample(machine_vec, N_train)

# select corresponding rows for your train and test dataset
# (all rows of the machines selected previously will form the train data)
df_train = df[df$Machine %in% train_machines,]
df_test = df[!df$Machine %in% train_machines,]
```

In the end the number of rows of your train and your test datasets should be equal to the number of rows of your original dataset, because you performed a split without losing any info. Also, a machine should belong only in the train dataset, or only in the test dataset, because that's the philosophy behind the split.